# jQuery: select tr's where td's meeting multiple criterias

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I was wondering, whether it's possible to select `<tr>`'s from a `<table>` where `<td>`'s meets multiple conditions. For example (see sample table at the end ):

> Get all `<tr>`'s where first column is "Audi" **AND** second column is
>   "red"

I've allready find out how to filter by one collumn:

```
$('tr:has(td:nth-child(1):contains("Audi"))').doSomeThing();
```

But my problem is how to filter with an **AND** condition like:

```
$('tr:has(td:nth-child(1):contains("Audi") && td:nth-child(2):contains("red"))').doSomeThing();
```

I know that there is the [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/), but since i'm searching for the .text() property it's not apropriate for my problem.

My sample table:

```
<table id="list">
<tr>
    <td>Audi</td>
    <td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Audi</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Audi</td>
    <td>green</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>BMW</td>
    <td>red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>BMW</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>BMW</td>
    <td>green</td>
</tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Thanx for your help!

Comment: $('tr:has(td:nth-child(1):contains("Audi")):has(td:nth-child(2):contains("red"))') should work

Comment: perfekt - works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

Use the `filter` method to narrow down your initial selection based on other conditions.

```
$('tr:has(td:nth-child(1):contains("Audi"))').filter(':has(td:nth-child(2):contains("red"))').doSomeThing();
```

If you're looking for a single selector, here is the less readable:

```
$('tr:has(td:nth-child(1):contains("Audi")):has(td:nth-child(2):contains("red"))').doSomeThing();
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/8Mnsf/2/

You could also improve readability somewhat by going for:

```
$('tr')
    .has('td:nth-child(1):contains("Audi")')
    .has('td:nth-child(2):contains("red")')
    .doSomeThing();
```

Comment: You should at least use the `.has()` method instead of the `:has` selector. It would make it a bit better.

Comment: @chumkiu I highly doubt my code is faster than bažmegakapa's, although it does have the benefit of being a one liner.

Comment: @Asad Is that ever a benefit?

Comment: @bažmegakapa Done. Yes, yes it is.

Comment: @Asad +1 for the last version. About oneliners: there is a tendency that the efforts to write shorter code result in tricky, unreadable, unmaintainable, hacky solutions.

Comment: I've tested both (and my deleted solution) with a table with almost 10 and 1000 tr. Yes I know... it's a very very very poor test, but your first solution is ten times faster (FF16). Your last version is 3 times slower than bažmegakapa solution. Ok, I Know is not a valid test, but 10 times faster...

Comment: @chumkiu If you are interested, you could set up a JsPerf and post the link here. Telling us that you have tested in an unknown way in an unknown environment that we cannot look at is not really useful.

Comment: @chumkiu,bazmegakapa Here's a jsPerf test: http://jsperf.com/has-vs-has-vs-filter As you can see, bazmegakapa's solution wins by a mile.

Comment: I've seen it. My apologize to @bažmegakapa ... but why if I do one cycle with an hand made date manage, I get an oppose result?

Comment: PS: my deleted solution is faster

Comment: here the snippet http://jsperf.com/jsfiltervshas. I still don't know why... but if I run the same codes just one time on page load, I have another result.

Comment: @chumkiu Your solution is faster, but it won't work if there is more than one result. Is it possible that with your "page load" test you are not looking at the right numbers or at least not from the right direction?

Comment: Ok. I know why. I've used in local jquery 1.7.2. With the 1.8 version Asad solution becomes slower. So it was a jquery version problem.

Comment: @bažmegakapa no. My solution works also with multiple results (tested... but I'm still sure of nothing now :))

Comment: @chumkiu My mistake - made a wrong assumption about the `.parent()` method.

Comment: @bažmegakapa try to test with jquery 1.7.2. Asad solution becomes faster. Maybe there is some additional check in 1.8 that slows the execution.

Comment: @chumkiu Would not spend much time on it, I will go with the readable version anyways. But the discussion and the tests were interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Your best choice would be to use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. Relying on jQuery's custom selectors (`:contains`, `:has`, etc.) is not the best idea in most cases, because the native `querySelectorAll()` cannot be used when available, which can become a performance problem.

From the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

> Because `:has()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using `:has()` cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   `$("your-pure-css-selector").has(selector/DOMElement)` instead.

Also a selector like that is hardly readable, so it reduces maintainability as well. A `filter()` method is simple readable code that can be reasonably commented as well if needed.

Something like this:

```
$('tr').filter(function () {
    var $cells = $(this).children('td');
    return $cells.first().text() === 'Audi'
         && $cells.eq(1).text() === 'red';
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AsAJF/)

Comment: thanx, this is also a nice solution! good to know the backround info